# Can I safely use 'getChildFragmentManager' inside 'onCreateView'?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Why getChildFragmentManager can obtain and replace a fragment before the view is created?

I have this code (inherited from a previous developer) and this worked successfully.

*simplified code*

```
public class HostFragment extends Fragment {    
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        MyFragment myfragment = new MyFragment();
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.framelayout, myfragment).commit();

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
       }  
   }
```

*fragment_layout.xml*

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm a little confused with this. How is it possible if the view does not exist yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. The commit() does not run immediately, it will execute after onCreateView(). But you best to call that after inflate. And the code will be more clear.

[`FragmentTransaction.commit()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit())

> Schedules a commit of this transaction. The commit does not happen immediately; it will be scheduled as work on the main thread to be done the next time that thread is ready.

Comment: Please, can you support this with references?